# How to install the new Firefox 64 bit

Tags: windows, firefox, 64-bit

I tried to download the setup file at this [link](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all/#en-US), but during installation process, I notice it still goes to folder Programs (x86), so I assume it still a 32 bit version.

Have anyone succeeded upgrade your browser, please show me how?

Comment: if the process is 64-bit why does it matter where it is installed?

Comment: Yes it doesn't matter. It is the first time I saw they point 64bit program to 32bit folder by default, so I just thought I got the wrong setup file.

Comment: open task manager to see if it's 32 or 64-bit version

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firefox 64-bit installs to the same folder. This will upgrade your Firefox to the 64-bit version.

Additionally, you can check your version by going to `about:buildconfig`. Under **Build platform**, the **target** should start with `x86_64` for 64-bit. 32-bit is `i686`

Answer (score 14):

#### I notice it still goes to folder Programs (x86)

This is a bug in the first release of the 64 bit version:

> The installer will upgrade Firefox to the 64-bit version but install it to C:\Program Files (x86), breaking Windows conventions of installing 64-bit applications to C:\Program Files.

Source [How to tell if Firefox is 32-bit or 64-bit](https://www.404techsupport.com/2015/12/tell-firefox-32-64/)

---

#### I assume it still a 32 bit version.

There are several ways to tell which version you have. See below.

---

#### How to tell if Firefox is 32-bit or 64-bit

> Mozilla published the Windows 64-bit installer for Firefox to the
> Download page with yesterday’s release of Firefox 43.0. You must have
> a 64-bit version of Windows to take advantage of the new version of
> the browser.
>
> There are two cosmetic bugs with the 64-bit version of Firefox that
> have been posted for a while without resolution.
>
> - The first bug
>   addresses installing the 64-bit bit version of Firefox when you have
>   an existing 32-bit version installed. The installer will upgrade
>   Firefox to the 64-bit version but install it to C:\Program Files
>   (x86), breaking Windows conventions of installing 64-bit applications
>   to C:\Program Files.
> - The second bug is asking for a designation of
>   which bit browser you are using in Firefox’s Help, About.
>
> Since both of those bugs make it difficult to tell which version of
> the browser you are using, here are two different ways to identify
> 32-bit vs 64-bit Firefox. User Agent
>
> In Firefox type `about:support` into the address bar. This will open up
> a page with a lot of information about your browser. From the User
> Agent line under Application Basics, you can see if this is the 32-bit
> version or 64-bit version running.
>
> **The 32-bit Firefox running on a 64-bit Windows 8.1 shows WOW64 in the
> User Agent.**
>
> [image: firefox43_x86]
>
> **The 64-bit Firefox running on a 64-bit Windows 8.1 shows Win64; x64.**
>
> [image: firefox43_x64]
>
> The 32-bit Firefox running on a 32-bit Windows will not include the
> Win64; x64 in the user agent.
>
> **Programs and Features**
>
> Another place that you can check is the Control Panel, Programs and
> Features. To uninstall a program, you can see the software name
> listed.
>
> **The 32-bit Firefox is listed as Mozilla Firefox 43.0 (x86 en-US).**
>
> [image: firefox43_x86_programs]
>
> **The 64-bit Firefox is listed as Mozilla Firefox 43.0 (x64 en-US).**
>
> [image: firefox43_x64_programs]

Source [How to tell if Firefox is 32-bit or 64-bit](https://www.404techsupport.com/2015/12/tell-firefox-32-64/)