# Firefox 55 64-bit won't start on Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, windows, firefox

The last few versions of Firefox (since about v52), I have tried to run the 64-bit version of the browser since I have a Windows 7 x64 machine. Firefox 32-bit has always run well on my computer for the last few years but I'd like to switch.

When I double-click Firefox to start it, it starts (shows up in running processes) but closes within 1 second before any UI even shows up on screen. I don't know how to find the culprit. This is what I've tried:

- Disable any security software (I don't have much; only a firewall)
- Uninstall and reinstall FF 64-bit
- Uninstall FF 32-bit
- Reboot the PC
- Start FF 64-bit in safe mode (by holding `shift` while I launch it)
- Move or rename my profile folder
- Use the offline (full) installer from [*download.mozilla.com*](https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-55.0.1-SSL&os=win64&lang=en-US)

I don't know what else to try. There is no error message. The installation seems to complete fine but when I launch the browser, the process just exits.

Any thoughts?

#### 2017-10-08

I've just tried FF 56 64-bit but ran into the same problem. I've also tried to start FF 64-bit from the command line without success:

```
firefox -safe-mode
firefox -ProfileManager
firefox -CreateProfile testprofile
firefox -P "testprofile"
firefox -headless
```

It always crashes immediately. I used [Nirsoft's AppCrashViewer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/app_crash_view.html) to take a look at the crash report and saw this:

```
Version=1
EventType=APPCRASH
EventTime=131519792389108198
ReportType=2
Consent=1
UploadTime=131519792389264199
ReportIdentifier=**REMOVED**
IntegratorReportIdentifier=**REMOVED**
Response.type=4
Sig[0].Name=Application Name
Sig[0].Value=firefox.exe
Sig[1].Name=Application Version
Sig[1].Value=56.0.0.6478
Sig[2].Name=Application Timestamp
Sig[2].Value=59cab571
Sig[3].Name=Fault Module Name
Sig[3].Value=StackHash_f982
Sig[4].Name=Fault Module Version
Sig[4].Value=0.0.0.0
Sig[5].Name=Fault Module Timestamp
Sig[5].Value=00000000
Sig[6].Name=Exception Code
Sig[6].Value=c0000005
Sig[7].Name=Exception Offset
Sig[7].Value=000000006ffe150a
DynamicSig[1].Name=OS Version
DynamicSig[1].Value=6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.27
DynamicSig[2].Name=Locale ID
DynamicSig[2].Value=1033
DynamicSig[22].Name=Additional Information 1
DynamicSig[22].Value=f982
DynamicSig[23].Name=Additional Information 2
DynamicSig[23].Value=f982514d3a20e62867484206e395a99a
DynamicSig[24].Name=Additional Information 3
DynamicSig[24].Value=3a8f
DynamicSig[25].Name=Additional Information 4
DynamicSig[25].Value=3a8fed7ce9e72a7f9314d43de4ce5f60
UI[2]=C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
UI[3]=Firefox has stopped working
UI[4]=Windows can check online for a solution to the problem.
UI[5]=Check online for a solution and close the program
UI[6]=Check online for a solution later and close the program
UI[7]=Close the program
LoadedModule[0]=C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
LoadedModule[1]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
LoadedModule[2]=C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
LoadedModule[3]=C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
LoadedModule[4]=C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\mozglue.dll
LoadedModule[5]=C:\Windows\system32\dbghelp.dll
LoadedModule[6]=C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
LoadedModule[7]=C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
LoadedModule[8]=C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\MSVCP140.dll
LoadedModule[9]=C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\VCRUNTIME140.dll
LoadedModule[10]=C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
LoadedModule[11]=C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\ucrtbase.DLL
LoadedModule[12]=C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\api-ms-win-core-timezone-l1-1-0.dll
LoadedModule[13]=C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\api-ms-win-core-file-l2-1-0.dll
LoadedModule[14]=C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll
LoadedModule[15]=C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll
LoadedModule[16]=C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-1.dll
LoadedModule[17]=C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-0.dll
LoadedModule[18]=C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll
LoadedModule[19]=C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll
LoadedModule[20]=C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll
LoadedModule[21]=C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll
LoadedModule[22]=C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll
LoadedModule[23]=C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll
LoadedModule[24]=C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\api-ms-win-crt-multibyte-l1-1-0.dll
LoadedModule[25]=C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll
LoadedModule[26]=C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll
LoadedModule[27]=C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll
LoadedModule[28]=C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll
LoadedModule[29]=C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
LoadedModule[30]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
LoadedModule[31]=C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
LoadedModule[32]=C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\nss3.dll
LoadedModule[33]=C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
LoadedModule[34]=C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
LoadedModule[35]=C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
LoadedModule[36]=C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
LoadedModule[37]=C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
LoadedModule[38]=C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
LoadedModule[39]=C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
LoadedModule[40]=C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
LoadedModule[41]=C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
LoadedModule[42]=C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
LoadedModule[43]=C:\Windows\system32\nvinitx.dll
LoadedModule[44]=C:\Windows\system32\Shell32.dll
LoadedModule[45]=C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
LoadedModule[46]=C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
LoadedModule[47]=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\CoProcManager\detoured.dll
LoadedModule[48]=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\CoProcManager\nvd3d9wrapx.dll
LoadedModule[49]=C:\Windows\system32\SETUPAPI.dll
LoadedModule[50]=C:\Windows\system32\CFGMGR32.dll
LoadedModule[51]=C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
LoadedModule[52]=C:\Windows\system32\DEVOBJ.dll
LoadedModule[53]=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\CoProcManager\nvdxgiwrapx.dll
LoadedModule[54]=C:\Windows\system32\guard64.dll
LoadedModule[55]=C:\Windows\system32\fltlib.dll
FriendlyEventName=Stopped working
ConsentKey=APPCRASH
AppName=Firefox
AppPath=C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
```

#### 2017-10-12

Today I discovered that FF 64bit will actually run within [Sandboxie](https://www.sandboxie.com/), the security program that creates a container around software as they run so they don't alter your system. I have tried to uninstall Sandboxie and reinstall FF 64bit, but it just keeps crashing if I try to run it outside the sandbox. Trying to `right-click + run as admin` actually goes far enough to show a crash notification:

```
  Firefox has stopped working

  Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: firefox.exe
  Application Version:  56.0.0.6478
  Application Timestamp:    59cab571
  Fault Module Name:    StackHash_f982
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   00000000
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 000000006ffe150a
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.27
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: f982
  Additional Information 2: f982514d3a20e62867484206e395a99a
  Additional Information 3: 3a8f
  Additional Information 4: 3a8fed7ce9e72a7f9314d43de4ce5f60
```

#### 2017-10-13

I've completely uninstalled FF (both 32 and 64bit) and deleted the Mozilla folder in AppData. I've also tried to delete leftover registry keys. I then install [Firefox 64bit Portable](https://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable) and tried to run it... same results :-(

Comment: Download Firefox installer from this [Mozilla FTP](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/) website. Open both installer with 7zip. Run it with a new user profile for each Firefox.

Comment: Was v54 64-bit OK? I haven't seen a v55 update alert (nor anything in the "About Firefox" dialog) yet. Also confirm where you downloaded v55 from.

Comment: @user3169 v55.0.1 has been available for several days and v55.0 for longer.

Comment: @DavidPostill I didn't say it wasn't.

Comment: @user3169 I wrote in the OP that I've had this problem since around v52. 64-bit FF will start but close within about a second (before the UI even shows up on screen).  I've never actually successfully used 64-bit FF on this machine, though 64-bit versions of other software run fine generally.  I downloaded v55 from [*download.mozilla.org*](https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-55.0.1-SSL&os=win64&lang=en-US)

Comment: @Biswa I mentioned that moving or renaming my current user profile doesn't help.  FF 64-bit doesn't get far enough even to create a new profile folder before it closes.  I'm using the offline full installer.

Comment: I have been using 64-bit FF for over a year without any problem. Did you uninstall the 32-bit version first? At this point there should be no Mozilla folder in Program Files (x86), only in Program Files. This is kind of old but may help - [How to install the new Firefox 64 bit](https://superuser.com/questions/1017684/how-to-install-the-new-firefox-64-bit)

Comment: Also make sure the  process Firefox.exe disappears when you exit Firefox. Sometimes this doesn't work right and you have to manually stop it.

Comment: @user3169 Uninstalling the 32-bit version hasn't helped. Not sure what else to try.

Comment: So now you have only 64-bit FF installed, right? So there is no Mozilla Firefox folder in Program Files (x86), right?  And Firefox.exe process is not running before you run Firefox? And if it then closes after a second, is the Firefox.exe process gone, or still running? Beyond that, I suppose it might be a conflict with some other software. Did you add/change any software or make any system changes around the time it stopped working?

Comment: I went back and read your question again. Now I am confused. 64-bit FF worked at some previous version and then stopped around FF52, or 64-bit FF never worked? And by "Windows 7 x64 machine", you mean a 64-bit CPU system running 64-bit Windows 7, right?

Comment: @user3169 64-bit FF never worked. I mentioned version 52 because that's the first time I tried (until then I only used 32bit FF).  By 64-bit, I mean the OS is 64-bit. I always assumed that this would mean the CPU supports 64bit. It's an Intel i7 (5th gen I think) but if you need the exact model #, I'll only be able to get it when I get home from work tonight

Comment: @user3169 I have an Intel Core i7-5700HQ, so definitely 64-bit capable. I also discovered one circumstance in which FF 64bit *will* run (update OP).

Comment: So basically you are running it as a portable app. It seems like something on your system is messing with FF 64-bit as installed software.

Comment: @BeetleJuice,You might want to ask on the Mozilla site (they have their own support forum).  I've occasionally run into an off-the-wall problem that turned out to be something esoteric and the subject matter experts there were able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Go to

> C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla

Erase the folder Firefox (**Warning will erase everything**)

Firefox should start normally.

Comment: I will try that this weekend. I'm curious though: why do you think this would affect just the 64bit FF? 32bit works fine.

Comment: This made no difference Jose. Thanks for the suggestion.